# Scraping the links from an isolated part of a Wikipedia article

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

So I:m trying to create a scraper that isolates the references section of the page, and then grabs the title and first paragraph or something similar from that web page.
At present, I have made it so it can isolate the references page, but am unsure how to progress as far as 'entering' the other links is concerned.

Here is my code so far

```
def customScrape(e1, master):
    session = requests.Session()
    # selectWikiPage = input("Please enter the Wikipedia page you wish to scrape from")
    selectWikiPage = e1.get()
    if "wikipedia" in selectWikiPage: #turn this into a re
        html = session.post(selectWikiPage)
        bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")
        findReferences = bsObj.find('ol', {'class': 'references'})  # isolate refereces section of page
        href = BeautifulSoup(str(findReferences), "html.parser")
        links = [a["href"] for a in href.find_all("a", href=True)]
        for link in links:
            print("Link: " + link)
    else:
        print("Error: Please enter a valid Wikipedia URL")
```

Comment: I don´t understand your question, why don´t u save the links you selected in an array and progress them by an similar mehtod and search for what u want ?

Comment: Um, how would one go about doing that? @SeeuD1

Comment: You just have to make a Method Like GetContents(Links) where you give ur Links as a parameter, there you can make a for Link in Links: where you iterate over the list and make a request for each Link and save the Data you reserve from it in an other array where you can work with your selected Data. This is only one way, you can also make a recursive method or something like that

Comment: do you want to enter the links located in references section? or any link in the first wikipedia page? Note that most of the links in references section are hosted in somewhere else than wikipedia!

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the direct question you asked, but others may find it useful... If you have a need to use Wikipedia as structure data, take a look at the related project: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Main_Page - this provides a structured data view of the a large portion of wikipedia, including links between topics, and is downloadable in its entirety for analysis without the lag of an internet connection.

Comment: please make your question more detail-full.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `customScrape` function, you can do this for every link:

```
ref_html = requests.get(link).text
```

to get the complete text from `link` (you don't need a `Session` unless you want to save cookies and other stuff between subsequent requests).
You can then parse `ref_html` to `find` title or first heading or whatever you like.

Your function could look like this:

```
import requests, requests.exceptions
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def custom_scrape(wikipedia_url):
    wikipedia_html = requests.get(wikipedia_url).text
    refs = BeautifulSoup(wikipedia_html, 'html.parser').find('ol', {
        'class': 'references'
    })
    refs = refs.select('a["class"]')

    for ref in refs:
        try:
            ref_html = requests.get(ref['href']).text
            title = heading = BeautifulSoup(ref_html, 'html.parser')

            title = title.select('title')
            title = title[0].text if title else ''

            heading = heading.select('h1')
            heading = heading[0].text if heading else ''
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print(ref['href'], e)  # some refs may contain invalid urls
            title = heading = ''

        yield title.strip(), heading.strip()  # strip whitespace
```

You can then go through the results:

```
for title, heading in custom_scrape('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow'):
    print(title, heading)
```